# Block until UIView loads text?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, blocking

I have a UIView with paging enabled.

I automaticly scroll to the next page:

```
[myView scrollToNextPage]
```

Now here I want the code to block until the next page is finished loading. scrollToNextPage calls a delegate method and I want to wait for it to finish before I keep going.

I'm not sure I want to use notifications because I don't want a notification every time the page is turned, just when I turn the page programaticly.

Thanks!

Comment: Just so to be clear, you call `scrollToNextPage` but you want to wait until it's loaded before actually scrolling to next page? Is the next page being loaded from web or do you just want to wait until perhaps the `UIView` is loaded?

Comment: The UIView is already loaded. There is a delegate method that responds to scrollToNextPage that updates the contents of the view. I want to wait for the delegate method to finish updating the view. Hope that's clear. Thanks!